# How to fix (TasksOperationsNotAllowed) ACR Tasks requests for the registry <containerRegistryName> and <password> are not permitted

Tags: azure, azure-container-registry, azure-container-service

When running the following command on Azure Cloud Shell getting the TasksOperationsNotAllowed error. How to fix?

Command:
az acr build --registry $REGISTRYNAME --image expressimage .

Errror:
(TasksOperationsNotAllowed) ACR Tasks requests for the registry  and  are not permitted. Please file an Azure support request at http://aka.ms/azuresupport for assistance. Code: TasksOperationsNotAllowed Message: ACR Tasks requests for the registry  and  are not permitted. Please file an Azure support request at http://aka.ms/azuresupport for assistance. Target: request

When running the following command on Azure Cloud Shell getting the TasksOperationsNotAllowed error. How to resolve?

Command:
az acr build --registry $REGISTRYNAME --image expressimage .

Errror:
(TasksOperationsNotAllowed) ACR Tasks requests for the registry  and  are not permitted. Please file an Azure support request at http://aka.ms/azuresupport for assistance. Code: TasksOperationsNotAllowed Message: ACR Tasks requests for the registry  and  are not permitted. Please file an Azure support request at http://aka.ms/azuresupport for assistance. Target: request

Comment: The error message "TasksOperationsNotAllowed" occurs when ACR Tasks requests for the registry and password are not permitted. To resolve this issue, you need to check if the user account used to authenticate the Azure CLI has the required permissions to perform ACR tasks. If the user account does not have the required permissions, you need to grant the necessary permissions to the user account. You can also try logging out and logging back in to the Azure CLI to refresh the authentication token.

Comment: References:

-   [Tutorial: Build and deploy container images in the cloud with Azure Container Registry Tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-tutorial-quick-task#build-in-azure-with-acr-tasks)
-   [Quickstart: Build and run a container image using Azure Container Registry Tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-quickstart-task-cli#quickstart-build-and-run-a-container-image-using-azure-container-registry-tasks)

Answer (score 0):

The error message "TasksOperationsNotAllowed" occurs when ACR Tasks requests for the registry and password are not permitted. To resolve this issue, you need to check if the user account used to authenticate the Azure CLI has the required permissions to perform ACR tasks. If the user account does not have the required permissions, you need to grant the necessary permissions to the user account. You can also try logging out and logging back in to the Azure CLI to refresh the authentication token.  You need to enable the "Admin user" option for the container registry. This option allows you to authenticate with the registry using a username and password. To enable this option, follow these steps:

1. Go to the Azure portal and navigate to your container registry.
2. Click on "Access keys" under "Settings".
3. Toggle the "Admin user" option to "Enabled".
4. Copy the username and password values displayed on the page.
5. Use these values to authenticate with the registry in your command.
   [image]

Once done, you can push your image into you registry and deploy accordingly

```xml
az login
az acr login --name <youracrname>
docker tag <the_name_you_want_to_show_in_ACR> <youracrname>.azurecr.io/<the_image_name_which_you_built>

docker push <youracrname>.azurecr.io/<the_name_you_want_to_show_in_ACR>
```

[image]

[image]

References:

- [Tutorial: Build and deploy container images in the cloud with Azure Container Registry Tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-tutorial-quick-task#build-in-azure-with-acr-tasks)
- [Quickstart: Build and run a container image using Azure Container Registry Tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-quickstart-task-cli#quickstart-build-and-run-a-container-image-using-azure-container-registry-tasks)

Comment: unrecognized arguments: --username --password when running the command "az acr build --registry $REGISTRY --image $IMAGE --username $USERNAME --password $PASSWORD ."